# Dashboards not rendering in Iframe in IE11 recent update Current IE Version: 11.1198.14393.0 KB4018271

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have an application which deals with iframes, but with Internet Explorer 11 the dashboards are not rendering in the iframe and it is resulting in a blank page. The request appears to be aborted when inspected in the console, I can see the following errors:

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied
File : CrossAssetKPIComparison, Line 1,Column 1
SCRIPT5: Access is denied
File : Widget-render, Line 1,Column 27468
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined
File : CrossAssetKPIComparison, Line 62, Column 5
```

Internet Explorer on my computer got recent updates with `KB4018271 (Current IE Version: 11.1198.14393.0)` as part of the system updates. I have gone through the microsoft community questions and seen a issue [mentioned](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6287fa2f-8843-431d-a6fc-342c34f2d96a/iframe-not-loading-after-installing-update-kb3154070?forum=ieitprocurrentver) in that they have replied, it got fix in the version  `MS16-084: Security update for Internet Explorer: July 12, 2016`. Can't we render dashboards in Iframe?

I have performed several troubleshooting measures with the Internet options of Internet Explorer11. If I access the same url(url which renders dashboards) outside (without loading into iframe), it works fine.

I have rolled back the update to the version `MS16-084: Security update for Internet Explorer: July 12, 2016`but still the problem continues. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately it is somewhat unclear what you are asking, please edit your question to make it clearer as to what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script bundle had jquery version `1.10.1` but once I updated it to version `1.10.2`, this issue was fixed.